# React: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: react-native, expo

I created an app in React using the command expo init and now I am getting the following error. Any suggestions?

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

For reference, this is my packages.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bookshare",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Please provide the content of `node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js`.

Comment: @DavidScholz `import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
`